# How can I change table's individual cell with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to use JavaScript to display a table and I would like to change some cell's background color in some particular condition.

Here is my code :

[image]

What I want is to change the color in middle column only like this

[image: This is what i want]

However, It ends up like this

[image: The whole row is changed]

```
below is my HTML

        <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="wellness.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wellness.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-title">
      <h3>Wellness Report</h3>
      <button class = "button search" type = "button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" >Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <div id = "showData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how to fix it. Thank you in advance

Comment: can you share your html code ?

Comment: You need to provide some html too.

Comment: What's inside the `col` array?

Comment: Please do NOT use an image for your code, we need the text (so we can try it, edit it, etc).

Comment: You're not checking the column number in your condition, should be `if (j === 1 && arrItems[1][col[i]] > 5 )`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (arrItems[j][col[i]] > 5) ...` instead of `if (arrItems[1][col[i]] > 5)` (so **`j`** instead of **`1`**)?

Comment: @DarthJDG  OMG, you are legend !! it works now but why is it ? Can you explain a bit further as I am really new to js. Thank in advance mate

Comment: @GaryFan That bit of code runs once for every cell in your table. Your condition was `true` at each iteration, as you explicitly checked the value of cell 1. Unless you also make sure you're currently processing cell 1, every cell in the row will be red.

Comment: @DarthJDG I think i got it. basically just stick the value of j to be 1 right?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (j === 1 && arrItems[1][col[i]] > 5 )
```

Comment: While this code might work, it's far better to explain how or why this is a solution.